# Get the first actual letter/number of a title

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I'm trying to get the first letter/digit of a title which is an NSString property of an object. The property may sometimes be nil or = @"", so I need to compensate for that. If the 
title begins with a number I need to return @"#". If it begins like "The Cup", I need to return "C" disregarding the "The ". If it is empty I need to return U for Unknown.

I have created the below script but it is extremely slow when searching 1000's of titles. Also sometimes I receive a `-[__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Index 1 out of bounds; string length 0`. I think it has to do with an empty string? Any other methods like regex or something I can use to speed up my query?

```
- (NSString *)firstLetterInTitle{
        NSString *newString = [self.title uppercaseString];
        NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            if([newString length] >= 1){
                if([f numberFromString:[newString substringToIndex:1]] != nil){
                    //All Numbers
                    _firstLetterInTitle = @"#";
                    return _firstLetterInTitle;
                }

                //" Hello"
                if([newString length] >= 2){
                    if([[newString substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@" "]){
                        newString = [newString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                             [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
                //Returns "Hello"
                    }
                }

        if([newString length] >= 5){
            if([[newString substringToIndex:4] isEqualToString:@"THE "]){
                newString = [newString substringFromIndex:4];
            }
        }

    }else{
        _firstLetterInTitle = @"U";
        return _firstLetterInTitle;
    }

    newString = [[newString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    if([newString length] >= 1){
        _firstLetterInTitle = [newString substringToIndex:1];
    }else{
        _firstLetterInTitle = @"U";
    }
        return _firstLetterInTitle;
}
```

Comment: FYI - regular expression rarely, if ever, make things faster.

Comment: thankyou Ill stray away from using that then

Comment: Why do you use a section title of "U" for empty values? Isn't that confusing to mix empty values with values that actually begin with a "U"?

Comment: @rmaddy it means Unknown Title. When I pole them in a table it will change null values to @"Unknown Title"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be somewhat faster

```
- (NSString *)firstLetterInTitle
{
    if (!self.title || ([self.title isEqualToString:@""])) {
        return @"U";
    }

    if ([[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[self.title characterAtIndex:0]]) {
        return @"#";
    }

    NSString *newString = [self.title uppercaseString];
    if (([newString hasPrefix:@"THE "]) && ([newString length > 4)) {
        newString = [newString substringFromIndex:4];
    }

    return [newString substringToIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: +1 for putting some order in the mess. My eyes started bleeding after the second `if` in the question.

Comment: The second `if` won't compile. Plus it would be faster to do `if ([[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[self.title characterAtIndex:0]])`. Using `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` will scan the whole string. You only want to check the first character.

Comment: The 3rd `if` should check the length 1st, then check the prefix. Otherwise you needlessly do a string compare on short strings.

Comment: The 1st if could be shortened to `if (self.title.length == 0)`.

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking you should probably check prefix first on the 3rd if. Realistically, a title is going to be > 4 almost always, and often not have THE as a prefix, so the length is an unnecessary check in most cases and only needed for the exception case where the prefix exists. You'd need to see the data set to be sure, but educated guess says length almost always evaluates to true whereas prefix mostly evaluates to false. So you'd put the one most likely to evaluate false first to minimize evaluations (even though it's more expensive)